# Closed form of a weighted binomial sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{i=0}^{i=k} ( c)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{m}{k-i}=?$$

What I tried:

$$ (1+x)^{m+n} =\sum_{r=0}^{m+n} ( \sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{m}{k}  \binom{n}{r-k}) x^r$$

So, this is the expression for binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{m+n}$ before simplification I thought of putting similar into the expression above. However, it cam to notice that $c^i$ sums at the same time as the co-efficent does (unlike the binomial product shown)

Comment: If $c\neq 1$ this is the definition of a gaussian hypergeometric function

Comment: hmm I would appreciate a simplified overview of it :D

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in comments
$$S(m,n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=k}  \binom{n}{i} \binom{m}{k-i}\,c^i=\binom{m}{k} \, _2F_1(-k,-n;m-k+1;c)$$ where appears [the gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).